# Trying to populate listbox in VB.NET from Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, listbox

I am getting an error on the line

```
reader = command.executereader()
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    connection.Open()

    'It comes here after opening the connection

    Dim command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Requestor Name", connection)


    Dim reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader

    reader = command.ExecuteReader()

    Do While (reader.Read())

        QUERBOX.Items.Add(reader.GetInt32(0))

    Loop

    reader.Close()

    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: it is clearly stating with error message that your query is wrong. debug that..

Comment: It highlighted the reader = command.executereader so I thought it was that. I will take a look at the query, thanks.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/

Answer (score 0):

[The constructor for `OleDbCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5yeecx59.aspx) expects a SQL query.  This is not valid SQL code:

```
Requestor Name
```

It's just text you typed into that string.  The database isn't going to *know what you mean* when you say random things to it.  Like any other computer system, it requires *valid code* to execute.

Something like this, for example:

```
SELECT Name FROM Requestors
```

(This is entirely a guess just to demonstrate the syntax, I don't know how your database is structured or what data you're trying to get from it.)

Comment: Got it. Basically I am trying to pull an entire row from the database into the list box. Eventually I will expand the code to pull the query fields from textboxes but for now I just want to get it functional.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


connection.Open()

'Requestor Name is the real error

Dim command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT [COLUMNAME] FROM [TABLENAME]", connection)


Dim reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader

reader = command.ExecuteReader()

Do While (reader.Read())

    QUERBOX.Items.Add(reader.GetInt32(0))

Loop

reader.Close()

connection.Close()
End Sub
```